# Mostrar fecha javascript en formato AAA-MM-DD

Tags: javascript

**  Necesito mostrar mi fecha a partir que yo rellene el input date y los tres campos: Edad, Mes, Dias y  mostrar cuandos años tiene la persona, meses y dias he intentado de varias manera pero no he podido dar con ello  **
[image: Necesito mostrar mi fecha en formato AAA-MM-DD javascript]

*Intente algo como lo el siguiente codigo que muestro a continuacion.*

```
document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded", e => {
        const
            d = document,
            $ = s => d.querySelector(s),
            $birthday = $("#birthday"),
            $year = $("#year"),
            $month = $("#month"),
            $day = $("#day");
        $birthday.placeholder = "YYYY/MM/DD"
        $birthday.oninput = function(e) {
            const content = this.value;
            if (content != "") {
                if (content.includes("/")) {
                    if (content.length == 10) {
                        if (content.indexOf("/") == 4) {
                            const [
                                year,
                                month,
                                day
                            ] = content.split("/");
                            const isNum = (...s) => !s.every(isNaN);
                            if (isNum(year, month, day)) {
                                $year.value = year;
                                $month.value = month;
                                $day.value = day;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que podrías intentar algo como lo siguiente: Primero estableces un id para cada input. Sabiendo que el campo que obtendrá la fecha completa debe venir en el siguiente formato **YYYY/MM/DD**, simplemente haces uso de la función [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) de javascript para obtener los datos, usando como separador slash **(/)**, lo que dividirá tu string y lo convertirá en un array de 3 posiciones, luego dices que los valores de cada elemento (Año, Mes y Día), corresponden a posiciones específicas de tu array.

```js
let birthday = document.getElementById('birthday');
let year = document.getElementById('year');
let month = document.getElementById('month');
let day = document.getElementById('day');

birthday.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let fecha = birthday.value.split('-');
  
  year.value = fecha[0];
  month.value = fecha[1] || '';
  day.value = fecha[2] || '';
})
```

```css
input {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input id="birthday" type="date" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD">
  <input id="year" type="text" placeholder="Year">
  <input id="month" type="text" placeholder="Month">
  <input id="day" type="text" placeholder="Day">
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, y como seria con un input type date? Asi es que lo necesito

Comment: Es básicamente lo mismo, es decir, sabes que un input type date no devuelve la fecha con slash **(/)** sino guiónes **(-)**, entonces en vez de hacer un split con slash, lo haces con guiónes para que tome los valores. Igualmente edité el script para que pruebes el resultado con un input de tipo date